# Copy text with same class to clipboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I have e.g. 20 lines of text, e.g.

```
<p class="textlist">Cheese</p>
<p class="textlist">Water</p>
<p class="textlist">Earth</p>
<p class="textlist">Helicopter</p>
<p class="textlist">Rabbit</p>
```

I wondered if anyone might be able to advise please, how I might be able to have a button on the page which a user can click, which copies the text values to the clipboard, so that all the user gets in their clipboard are the p innerHTML values in a list split by line breaks, e.g.

```
Cheese
Water
Earth
Helicopter
Rabbit
```

The example above is just a simple example, rather than the finished product I'l be working with, just something to use as an example to demonstrate the point.

I was thinking it might be possible using Javascript / jQuery / accessing the DOM, but I don't know how one would do it.

Comment: https://waaave.com/tutorial/jquery/copy-text-to-clipboard-using-jquery/
Just check this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.map` in Jquery to collect all P tag data and `append` the text to some other element

```
 var data = $("p").map(function () {
    return "<div>" + $(this).text() + "</div>";
}).get();

$(".getDiv").append(data);
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/U9hDx/)